# How can I add custom buttons to bootstrap-datetimepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I want to do a certain action when a button in bootstrap-datetimepicker widget is clicked but it seems we can't do so, thus I would like to add my custom buttons.

For example, I am using two fields and each of them is having the bootstrap-datetimepicker attached. Now what I want to do is if someone clicks on clear button in widget the time in both fields should get cleared.

The tool I am making can be used to find time of any city in the world with respect to any particular city (for now its Pune, India).

Check the tool I am making [here.](http://uditchugh.me/projects/timeconverter/)

Check the code [here.](https://github.com/udit96rc/TimeConverter)

Answer (score 0):

Interesting project.
To get what you want, get the bootstrap-datetimepicker sources and change it to fit your needs.
https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker

Comment: Will try that. But I was looking for an easier alternative.